# How can the surface integral (for a surface defined with parameters) be derived without using vectors?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

It is possible to derive the arclength analytically by using the Pythagorean theorem:

given a curve y(x), infinitestimal length dl along the curve can be given as: 
$(dl)^2 = (dx)^2 + (dy)^2$

Dividing both sides by $(dx)^2$,
$(dl/dx)^2 = 1 + (y')^2$

Thus,
$$l = \int \sqrt{1 + (y')^2}\,dx$$

For a surface defined parametrically, $z(x,y)$, the infinitestimal area $ds$ should be:
$(ds)^2 = (dx\, dy)^2 + (dx \,dz)^2 + (dz\, dy)^2$

How do I actually arrive at this (the aforementioned equation)? I tried multiplying $dz$ by $dl$ to get the area of an infitestimal parallelogram, but that doesn't work. I know I can do it using vectors, but what is the analytic approach?

Comment: There isn't a nice approach, because the only intuitive formula for the area${}^2$ of that infinitesimal parallelogram is $(dx^2+dz^2)(dy^2+dz^2)\,\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle of the parallelogram. But the only nice formula for $\theta$ uses the cross product.

Comment: I feared as much....Thanks @MikeEarnest!